# Beefy fince retired vault lp break up

Tags: solidity

I have two lps from beefy finance. The vault is retired and there is no liquidity on the solidly dex i used to create pair.  I cant even find in wallet.   Is there any hopw of recovering funds by breaking up lp ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.